# Beginner here, How do i re-enable transform handle dots? Version 2.8

Tags: node-editor, edit-mode, transforms

The little dots attached to the handle lines are gone completely. The dots in node editor are missing also, I'm sure I've hotkeyed them away by mistake. Can anyone help me get them back? Thank you.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What dots are you talking about exactly? Please edit your question and add a screenshot or something. Also, Blender 2.79 or 2.8?

Comment: In the Overlay menu of the 3D view, make sure "handles" is checked : https://ibb.co/fGT0Gxx . However, I can't see how this could be related to the node editor.